# iOS swift - go to the next custom UITabBarController programatically

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I created a storyboard. The first screen is Launch screen(custom UIViewController called LaunchViewController) and the next screen is custom UITabBarController called SampleTabViewController.

I want to have it automatically go to the SampleTabViewController after 2 seconds on the LaunchViewController.

But some samples that I have found is only from the custom UIViewController to custom UIViewController.

I already set 'sampleTabViewController' on screen associated with "SampleTabViewController" on the storyboard.

Here is my code.

```
class LaunchViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("LaunchViewController is initialized");

    let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sampleTabViewController")


        self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

    }
}
```

I tried "self.presentViewController(CareGiverViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)". It works, but the next screen is blank.

I just started learning iOS app with Swift.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your LaunchViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set TabbarViewController as rootViewController .

Replace with your push ViewController lines :

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sampleTabViewController") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but what do you mean "Try to set TabbarViewController as rootViewController "?  Do I need to change something on storyboard?

Comment: I didn't set the rootViewController. I just used this code. It works. 

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("careGiverViewController") as! UITabBarController
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller


But how should I add animation?

Comment: Yes. it goes to the next controller that I want to target. How should I add a animation, something like horizontal flipping?  I used a button to go to the next controller before.